# Automatic switching between drop-down menus (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to automatically switch between dropdown menus.

I have two drop-down menus, when I select the first menu, the second menu content changes depending on this menu, I want it to automatically switch to the second menu and show the list content.

However, it goes to the second menu but does not show its content.

It appears when I click again.

My codes are below. Can you help me?

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownListOuterAccounts"
        style="@style/MyDropDownMenuOuterStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/dropDownListAccounts"
            style="@style/MyEditTextInputInnerStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adapter="@{arrayAdapterAccounts}"
            android:hint="@string/choose_account"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownListOuterSubaccounts"
        style="@style/MyDropDownMenuOuterStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dropDownListOuterAccounts">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/dropDownListSubaccounts"
            style="@style/MyEditTextInputInnerStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adapter="@{arrayAdapterSubaccounts}"
            android:hint="@string/choose_subaccount"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
        binding.dropDownListAccounts.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {

            binding.dropDownListOuterAccounts.setHelperText(accountList.get(position).getAccountTypeName());

            binding.dropDownListSubaccounts.setText(null);
            binding.dropDownListOuterSubaccounts.setHelperText(null);

            subaccountsList.set(
                    subaccountList
                            .stream()
                            .filter(subaccounts -> subaccounts.getAccountId().equals(accountList.get(position).getAccountId())).collect(Collectors.toList())
            );

            List<String> subaccountNames =
                    subaccountsList.get()
                            .stream()
                            .map(Subaccounts::getSubaccountName)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

            binding.setArrayAdapterSubaccounts(
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(
                            requireContext(),
                            com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            subaccountNames));
            
            binding.dropDownListSubaccounts.setFocusable(true);
            binding.dropDownListSubaccounts.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            binding.dropDownListSubaccounts.requestFocus();
            binding.dropDownListSubaccounts.performClick();

        });
```